# Is there a way to conver this RAW query into Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have this line of query that works on MySQL via localhost and i want to use it on my Laravel but i dont know how to convert or translate my code into Eloquent.

The 2 models are in relationship with each other. this is what i tried with my code.

**Statuses**

```
public function reqs(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Reqs','reqs_id','id');
}
```

**Reqs**

```
public function statuses()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Statuses','reqs_id','id');
}
```

This is what i tried and it cant get what i want

```
$reqs = Statuses::with('reqs')->
where('status','=',$status)->
where('user_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

This on the other hand is working

```
DB::select('SELECT * from `statuses`, `reqs`
            WHERE `statuses`.`status` = ?
            AND `reqs`.`id` = `statuses`.`reqs_id`
            AND `reqs`.`user_id` = ?
            ', [$status,auth()->user()->id]);
```

i got what i expected but i want to know if there is a eloquent way.
THANKS.

Comment: how does your models looked like? what you have tried..?

Comment: Yes there is. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't select from two tables with Eloquent, you need to explicitly join the other table on. You don't need the `select()` part of this query but you probably should be explicit about what fields you want so that you get the data you expect.

```php
Status::select('statuses.*')
    ->join('reqs', 'reqs.id', '=', 'statuses.reqs_id')
    ->where('statuses.status', $status)
    ->where('reqs.user_id', auth()->id())
    ->get();
```